# I want to add a Multiline InputDialog to my Ruble

Tags: ruby, jruby, aptana

Ok so I would really like to be able to add a multiline (textarea) InputDialog to my ruble.

I've worked around the limitations in Ruble::UI and created my own module that I load with my ruble when I want more then the default dialogs the Ruble::UI provides. Because of this I've been able to add multiselect dialogs and even gotten the Multiline InputDialog to work by creating a override class and then passing the getTextStyle method my own values to make it multiline.

The problem comes in that the dialog displays a multiline text box but it's height is still set to one line, so it essentially still just a single line box. I know from Eclipse plugin dev how to create the multiline dialog in Java, I just can't figure out how to make it happen in a ruble using jruby.

Here is my current code in ruby

## Used to request a Multi Dialog

```
  class MultiInputDialog < org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.InputDialog
    def getInputTextStyle
      org.eclipse.swt.SWT::MULTI | org.eclipse.swt.SWT::BORDER | org.eclipse.swt.SWT::V_SCROLL
    end
  end
```

And here is what the code to do it in Java would like.

## Java override

```
InputDialog dlg = new InputDialog(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell(), "Test", "Please input text.",
      "Test-Text", null) {

    /**
     * Override this method to make the text field multilined
     * and give it a scroll bar. But...
     */
    @Override
    protected int getInputTextStyle() {
      return SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL;
    }

    /**
     * ...it still is just one line high.
     * This hack is not very nice, but at least it gets the job done... ;o)
     */
    @Override
    protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
      Control res = super.createDialogArea(parent);
      ((GridData) this.getText().getLayoutData()).heightHint = 100;
      return res;
    }
  };
  dlg.open();
```

So you can see I've figured out how to override the getInputTextStyle, but everthing I've tried to mimic the override of createDialogArea() has falied. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  class MultiInputDialog < org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.InputDialog
    def getInputTextStyle
      org.eclipse.swt.SWT::MULTI | org.eclipse.swt.SWT::BORDER | org.eclipse.swt.SWT::V_SCROLL
    end
    def createDialogArea(parent)
      control = super(parent)
      getText.getLayoutData.heightHint = 100;
      control
    end
  end
```

Cheers,
Max

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. It also helps me understand better how I can use some more of the Eclipse API in my Ruble.